# Why Markers points are not aligned with yAxis in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, highcharts

I have made a line chart with two different lines, each line is mapped against time in xAxis but the points in the plot does not coincide with the yAxis. The values in the markers are not at all matching with the tick options. I am not sure what is going wrong. This weird behaviour happens if there are two data points exactly in the same time. I am not aware what to do? The image is as follows:-

[image]
The code can be found out in fiddle as well out here http://jsfiddle.net/Cp73s/5394/
The Configuration and data is as mentioned below:-

```
   "options": {
      "chart": {
        "type": "line",
        "zoomType": "yx",
        "animation": true,
        "spacingBottom": 15,
        "spacingTop": 5,
        "spacingLeft": 10,
        "spacingRight": 10,
        "reflow": true
      },
      "exporting": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "colors": ["#2C91DE", "#165A8E"],
      "plotOptions": {
        "line": {
          "marker": {
            "symbol": "circle"
          }
        },
        "series": {
          "stacking": "normal",
          "marker": {
            "lineWidth": 0,
            "lineColor": null,
            "enabled": true,
            "radius": 5
          }
        }
      },
      "tooltip": {
        "shared": true,
        "crosshairs": true,
        "followPointer": true,
        "borderColor": null
      }
    },
    "title": {
      "text": "Blood Pressure"
    },
    "loading": false,
    "xAxis": {
      "startOnTick": true,
      "endOnTick": true,
      "tickInterval": 86400000,
      "type": "datetime",
      "title": {
        "text": "Date/Time"
      },
      "labels": {
        "rotation": -60,
        "format": "{value:%m-%d-%Y}",
        "align": "right"
      }
    },
    "series": [{
      "name": "Systolic",
      "data": [{
        "x": 1472980051000,
        "y": 43,
        "fillColor": "#e74c3c"
      }, {
        "x": 1472980051000,
        "y": 34,
        "fillColor": "#e74c3c"
      }, {
        "x": 1473066451000,
        "y": 120,
        "fillColor": "#e74c3c"
      }, {
        "x": 1473697392000,
        "y": 119,
        "fillColor": "#2ecc71"
      }, {
        "x": 1473710858000,
        "y": 120,
        "fillColor": "#2ecc71"
      }, {
        "x": 1473710858000,
        "y": 120,
        "fillColor": "#2ecc71"
      }, {
        "x": 1473711048000,
        "y": 114,
        "fillColor": "#2ecc71"
      }, {
        "x": 1473711048000,
        "y": 114,
        "fillColor": "#2ecc71"
      }, {
        "x": 1474548167000,
        "y": 95,
        "fillColor": "#f1c40f"
      }, {
        "x": 1474647485000,
        "y": 106,
        "fillColor": "#f1c40f"
      }, {
        "x": 1474647535000,
        "y": 106,
        "fillColor": "#f1c40f"
      }, {
        "x": 1474654052000,
        "y": 93,
        "fillColor": "#f1c40f"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Diastolic",
      "data": [{
        "x": 1472980051000,
        "y": 53,
        "fillColor": "#e74c3c"
      }, {
        "x": 1472980051000,
        "y": 120,
        "fillColor": "#e74c3c"
      }, {
        "x": 1473066451000,
        "y": 32,
        "fillColor": "#e74c3c"
      }, {
        "x": 1473697392000,
        "y": 70,
        "fillColor": "#2ecc71"
      }, {
        "x": 1473710858000,
        "y": 80,
        "fillColor": "#2ecc71"
      }, {
        "x": 1473710858000,
        "y": 80,
        "fillColor": "#2ecc71"
      }, {
        "x": 1473711048000,
        "y": 68,
        "fillColor": "#2ecc71"
      }, {
        "x": 1473711048000,
        "y": 68,
        "fillColor": "#2ecc71"
      }, {
        "x": 1474548167000,
        "y": 55,
        "fillColor": "#f1c40f"
      }, {
        "x": 1474647485000,
        "y": 57,
        "fillColor": "#f1c40f"
      }, {
        "x": 1474647535000,
        "y": 59,
        "fillColor": "#f1c40f"
      }, {
        "x": 1474654052000,
        "y": 54,
        "fillColor": "#f1c40f"
      }]
    }],
    "yAxis": {
      "title": {
        "text": "mmHg"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why would they? The axis labels are marking regular intervals - the beginning of each day. Your data points are plotting events at specific times during those days, and are placed accordingly. This is not weird behavior, it is expected behavior - the points are plotted exactly where you've told the chart to plot them. What is the behavior that you would like to see in your scenario?

Comment: @jlbriggs So could you help me to understand how to get a proper graph rather than this. I want these in proper time and the intervals can vary but I dont want this behavior. On the other hand any document will also be helpful. I have put up a fiddle for the same. Thanks

Comment: @jlbriggs I would like to see the line chart so that the points show the exact values in the yAxis. Please help.

Comment: Well, you'll have to define what a "proper" chart is :) Again - the chart is plotting them in proper time, but that seems to be what your complaint is. You have to choose between 1) plotting all points at their proper x value, or 2) plotting all points sequentially without regard to their proper time. If your time intervals vary, you definitely can't have both.

Comment: If your primary goal is making the x axis ticks align to each point, use the `tickPositions` property, or the `tickPositioner` function - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions | http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: @jlbriggs I want the points to align to yAxis Properly. As in when you see the image the point with value 34 is going above 200 mark for the yAxis. So I want to get that right. xAxis is proper as of now. Hope I am not irritating you by my questions. I am a bit new to highcharts. Thanks.

Comment: My apologies - I misread your post, and thought you were referring to the x axis. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I misread your post as referring to the x axis.

In your `plotOptions`, you are specifying:

```
"stacking": "normal"
```

You are telling the chart to stack the series on top of each other.

Remove that, and the values reflect the proper `y` values:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/Cp73s/5396/

Comment: Ah!! Thanks a lot for this solution. Yes it works. And also thanks for pointing me out to the document for irregular interval document.  :) Glad. Here comes you points.